# Does the ethernet connection speed shown actually limit the connection speed?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, speed

The ethernet connection speed shown in the image below is about half that of the speed provided by my ISP (which is 200mbits/s). While the cat 5e cables I have are 1.0Gb/s capable I am having to use 200mbit/s powerline adapters to connect this computer.

*In theory*, the hardware is 200mbit/s capable, so should be able to make use of the 200mbit/s the ISP provides (I am well aware that thats an up-to speed, but the "real" speed should be over 100mbits/s).

So the question is, does the speed shown in the image below represent the maximum speed of the connection? Or is the connection actually 200mbit/s but thats not a speed thats shown?

The router "Attached Devices" Page shows a speed of 1Gb/s, and the connection speed also shows this when the system is plugged directly into the router.

[image: Connection Speed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In theory, the hardware is 200mbit/s capable,

But it isn’t. Your PC’s network interface is part of “the hardware”. On a link from A to B, the slowest segments determines the link bandwidth.

It’s even worse though: Your powerline setup is very unlikely to reach the advertised maximum bandwidth of 200 MBit/s. You can count yourself lucky if you manage to squeeze 100 MBit/s through. The powerline adapter’s Ethernet interface is most likely limited to 100 MBit/s.

Now, as to the specific number displayed there: It is provided by the driver. The driver can simply lie. That’s the case with most virtual network adapters. Yours isn’t virtual, however.

So the answer to your original question is: This number in itself means nothing and is most certainly not a limit of any kind.

If (and only if) the driver accurately reports the currently negotiated connection speed, the number represents the theoretical maximum transfer rate. On Ethernet, you can more or less reach this speed. With wireless connections, you need to keep in mind the shared nature of the medium. The speed indicated there can never be reached.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this PC's ethernet port is Gigabit capable and the powerline adapters both have "200mb per second" written on them - do you think that label is not realistic in the real world?

Comment: @Sam3000 No, it’s not. It’s as realistic as wireless speed labels. The power line is also a shared medium, after all.

Comment: The number isn't meaningless. With an Ethernet-to-Powerline adapter, the Ethernet side has a speed independent from the Powerline side, because the Ethernet standards specify a particular, fixed signal rate for each 'speed'. If your network card says 100 Mbps, it _means_ 100 Mbps.

Comment: @grawity But it is. :D The OpenVPN network adapter used to always display 10 MBit/s, regardless of whether you were currently transferring at well over 100 MBit/s. Of course, it’s generally meaningful for regular network adapters.

Comment: @Daniel: But this _is_ a regular adapter. Powerline adapters have a physical Ethernet connection that goes into a physical Ethernet card over a physical Cat5 cable. I don't see how your OpenVPN example is _at all_ related to that – of course a virtual interface could lie, but this _is not_ virtual.

Answer (score 1):

The speed shown in the connection status is the theoretical limit of your connection. Either your adapter is limited to 100Mbps or something between you are your modem are, generally a router or switch would get you stuck at 100Mbps.